# Wrapping JavaScript FFI in Either

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I am very new to `JavascriptFFI` and will very much appreciate help here.

I have a working javascript code to grab image as `FILE URI` from camera (via cordova camera plugin). Now, it can return either error or file uri on success.  We want to map them to `Left Int Text` and `Right  GHCJS.DOM.Types.File` (not sure if I got the type of `FILE URI` right).

Here is the javascript code (untested since I modified it off the tested one to return just fileuri or error, instead of displaying it in the browser).

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      console.log("success");
      return imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function for testing
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as binary data 
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
       console.log("failure");
      return[1, message];
    }

    </script>
```

I will appreciate pointers on how to do the FFI to `navigator.camera.getPicture` with ghcjs-dom-0.2.3.1 (I am using it with Reflex) such that returned result is in Either.

I can then wrap the `File URI` in `ByteString` (I think through Cordova file api to convert it first to `arraybuffer`) and send it off to remove server for persistence.